# Importing Apache Log with Logstash to Big Query

Tags: parsing, logstash

i am trying to upload Apache log files into Big Query.
I have installed logstash and the contrib plugin (for Big Query).

When i configure the stdin/stdout, i see all fields with the good parsing.
When i configure the stdin/output big query, i have lines into Big Query.

But when i configure the input file and the output big query, i have nothing into BQ.
I haven't any errors.

There is my log file (/logfile/toto.log):
9.219.129.178 - - [24/Aug/2014:06:33:20 +0200] "GET /2011/03/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7478 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"

If you have any ideas. Thanks a lot.

There is my config for logstash

```html
input {
  file {
    path => "/logfile/toto.log"
    start_position => beginning
    exclude => "*.gz"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"  }
  }
  date {
     match => ["timestamp","dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
     locale => "en"
     remove_field=>["timestamp"]
  }
}

output {
    google_bigquery {
      project_id => "caramel-source-750"
      dataset => "logs"
      csv_schema => "message:STRING,version:STRING,timestamp:STRING,host:STRING,path:STRING,clientip:STRING,ident:STRING,auth:STRING,verb:STRING,request:STRING,httpversion:STRING,response:STRING,bytes:STRING,referrer:STRING,agent:STRING"
      key_path => "/var/www/API-Project-XXX.p12"
      key_password => "notasecret"
      service_account => "XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
      temp_directory => "/tmp/logstash-bq"
      temp_file_prefix => "logstash_bq"
      date_pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00"
      flush_interval_secs => 2
      uploader_interval_secs => 30
      deleter_interval_secs => 30
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you verified that Logstash is processing the logs correctly at all and that the problem is the `google_bigquery` plugin specifically? I always use a `stdout` output to verify that messages go through the pipeline correctly before attempting to send them anywhere else. Is there something interesting in the Logstash logs? What if you start Logstash with `--verbose` or even `--debug`?

Comment: Nothing appends. I have many logs with : detect file ok , grok loading pattern ok., pipeline stared. And after nothing

Comment: And new data is being appended to the files?

Comment: When i add some data, they arrived in BQ. Thanks a lot. Yessss :)